# I can't install anything by terminal

Tags: software-installation, matlab

Recently I installed matlab, and now I can't install anything via terminal because this screen always appears.

[image: Screen that don't let me install anything]

What should I do to remove that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It obviously wants you to enter where matlab is installed, as you can read in the text. Run the command `which matlab` to get the path of the matlab executable.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of Matlab, so cannot work all of this out for you.  But you will figure this out. Matlab is trying to complete its install and until all of its pieces find each other, it is going to keep launching that crud.

The key thing is that the Matlab installer fiddles with your PATH and also it looks like it changes your shell configuration.  If the installer works correctly and finishes all of its work, it will put its own directory at the front of your PATH.  However, something wrong happened in your install so one part of matlab cannot find the other.  In your ~/.bashrc, did you insert something that tries to launch Matlab every single time you open a session?

So, figure out why that matlab configurator launches when you open a terminal.  Correct that.  (I would get a different terminal program and see if problem happens there too.  Probably will.)  I suspect matlab install has inserted something in your home folder startup settings, such as "~/.bashrc" or .profile or simiar. It is going to keep happening until you either remove that bit from your config or fix your matlab install.

I'm curious to know what happens if you launch other shell sessions. For example, in Emacs, if you run M-x eshell, does that Matlab harassment still preset itself.